# Include "in X amount days" in workflow that triggers every 10 days until End Date?

Tags: workflow, email-template

I have a workflow that triggers when a record is created and sends and email 45 days before the end date, warning the Manager that the thing ends on that date.

I'd like to use the same email template every 10 days after that, triggered by another timed action in the same workflow.

So it will say in the first email, "The thing ends in 45 days."

In the second email, "The thing ends in 35 days." etc.

How can I calculate and embed the XX days values, based on the end date that is in the record?

Answer (score 1):

Sussed it!

```
subject="Assignment for {!relatedTo.Resource__r.Name} Ends in {!relatedTo.ForecastEndDate__c - TODAY()} Days"
```